# TListViewItem Checked property isn't visually synced

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have a TListView, I add a new item into it when user drops a file onto it. When he clicks on any item it toggles between checked and unchecked states.

```
procedure TMainForm.UI_WorkListItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject;
ItemIndex: Integer; const LocalClickPos: TPointF;
const ItemObject: TListItemObject);
begin
TListView(Sender).Items[ItemIndex].Checked:=not TListView(Sender).Items[ItemIndex].Checked;
end;
```

The problem is, visually nothing happens.

Comment: I'm no expert in FireMonkey (I never use it), but it looks like the `TListViewItem.Checked` property is not hooked up to anything visual when the `TListView.EditMode` is false, unless you use a LiveBinding (or other code) to attach the current `Checked` value to something yourself. When `EditMode` is True, I do see the `Checked` property influences the item's native edit checkbox, but I don't see the value persisted when `EditMode` is subsequently toggled.

Comment: At this point I really question myself if I want to stick with FMX any longer. No TRichEdit replacement, no TWebBrowser for desktop, half of components I've tried so far don't work as expected (I'm unable to put anything onto a TStatusBar, ffs, mate) and so on.

Comment: Well maybe you use this component in a wrong way. There is no need to set the checked state on clicking. Just turn on EditMode and the component shows the checkboxes and will handle the checked state. After selecting start the action and read the checked state and process as you like

Comment: It's possible. I know nothing about TListView's Edit mode, and the help tells me only so much.

Comment: Try TListBox instead of TListView for that. TMS Software has a cross platform WebBrowser and RichEdit component. http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfmxpack.asp